# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in iOS objective c result differs from Android

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using the AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Android application. Code is like-

```
    private static String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    private static String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static String DIGEST = "MD5";

    private static Cipher cipher;
    private static SecretKey password;
    private static IvParameterSpec IVParamSpec;
    private final static String pvtkey="GDNBCGDRFSC$%#%=";

    //16-byte private key
    private static byte[] IV = pvtkey.getBytes();

    public PassWordEncryptor() {
        try {

            //Encode digest
            MessageDigest digest;           
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST);            
            password = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest(pvtkey.getBytes()), ALGORITHM);

            //Initialize objects
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            IVParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.i(Lams4gApp.TAG, "No such algorithm " + ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println( "No such padding PKCS7"+ e);
        }
    }
    /**
    Encryptor.

    @text String to be encrypted
    @return Base64 encrypted text

    */
    public String encrypt(byte[] text) {

        byte[] encryptedData;

        try {

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, password, IVParamSpec);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(text);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            System.out.println( "Invalid key  (invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc)."+ e);
            return null;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            System.out.println( "Invalid or inappropriate algorithm parameters for " + ALGORITHM+ e);
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            System.out.println( "The length of data provided to a block cipher is incorrect"+ e);
            return null;
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println( "The input data but the data is not padded properly."+ e);
            return null;
        }               
        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData,Base64.DEFAULT);

    }
```

I need similar code in iOS Objective C. Encryption and Decryption results should be same in android and iOS.
Kindly provide the same algorithm for Objective C.

I am using iOS code as-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSData *encodingData=[self encrypt:[@"slapkh"
                                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *encodingResult = [NSString base64StringFromData:encodingData length:[encodingData length]];


}

- (NSData *) encrypt:(NSData *) plainText {
            return [self transform:kCCEncrypt data:plainText];
}

- (NSData *) decrypt:(NSData *) cipherText {
            return [self transform:kCCDecrypt data:cipherText];
}
- (NSData *) transform:(CCOperation) encryptOrDecrypt data:(NSData *) inputData {
     Cipher* cipher = [[Cipher alloc]initWithKey:@"GDNBCGDRFSC$%#%="];
    NSString* Key = cipher.cipherKey;

    // kCCKeySizeAES128 = 16 bytes
   // CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH = 16 bytes
   NSData* secretKey = [Cipher md5:Key];

   CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
   CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

   uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
   memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

   status = CCCryptorCreate(encryptOrDecrypt,
                            kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                            [secretKey bytes], kCCKeySizeAES128, iv, &cryptor);

   if (status != kCCSuccess) {
       return nil;
   }

   size_t bufsize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, (size_t)[inputData length],
                                             true);

   void * buf = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(uint8_t));
   memset(buf, 0x0, bufsize);

      size_t bufused = 0;
      size_t bytesTotal = 0;

      status = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor, [inputData bytes], (size_t)[inputData length],
                               buf, bufsize, &bufused);

      if (status != kCCSuccess) {
          free(buf);
          CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
          return nil;
      }

      bytesTotal += bufused;

      status = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor, buf + bufused, bufsize - bufused, &bufused);

      if (status != kCCSuccess) {
          free(buf);
          CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
          return nil;
      }

      bytesTotal += bufused;

      CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);

      return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:bytesTotal];
  }
```

But the results for Android and iOS Differs as-
Text to encrypt: slapkh
key: GDNBCGDRFSC$%#%=

Android result: jN2p1yAdBJLRmoHq+k9KtA==\n

iOS Resut: tbaSJFv5mGyZ9t/+kOw+gg==

Comment: For starters, you use different IVs: in android code it's `pvtkey.getBytes()`, but in ios code it's just zeros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in iOS objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253823/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-ios-objective-c)

Comment: @Roman That question was closed because initially it was missing code, code was added but the question was not re-opened so this is a valid question.

Comment: Thanks @Roman for your reply. But i need the same result for both because same algorithm is also running for web which is validating the authentication with the same key. Please suggest me the exact equivalent method for encryption and decryption so that i can get the same results for both Android and iOS.

Comment: @zaph: Any method to get similar results for both Android and iOS. I have posted both codes in the question. Please help.

Comment: I'm getting use of undeclared identifier 'Cipher'..which pod do I need to install? or any framework needs to be added?

Answer (score 2):

After spending time dealing with this, I got success in ANDROID(java) and IOS (Objc) using AES with the codes below:

**ANDROID CODE**

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class SecurityUtils {

        private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
        private static final String MODE = "AES";
        private static final String IV = "AEE0715D0778A4E4";
        private static final String KEY= "9336365521W5F092BB5909E8E033BC69";

        public static  String encrypt(String value ) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
            byte[] values = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeBytes(values);
        }

        public static  String decrypt(String value) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
            byte[] values = Base64.decode(value);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(values));
        }
    }
```

**TESTING ANDROID**

```
   try {
        String encrypted = SecurityUtils.encrypt("My Secret Text");
        String decrypted = SecurityUtils.decrypt(encrypted);
        Log.e("encrypted", encrypted);
        Log.e("decrypted", decrypted);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("AES", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

**IOS CODE**

**Header file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SecurityUtils : NSObject

+ (NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)plainText error:(NSError **)error;
+ (NSString *)decrypt:(NSString *)plainText error:(NSError **)error;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**Implementation file**

```
NSString *const IV = @"AEE0515D0B08A4E4";
NSString *const KEY =  @"9336565521E5F082BB5929E8E033BC69";


#import "SecurityUtils.h"


@implementation SecurityUtils


+ (NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)plainText error:(NSError **)error {
    NSMutableData *result =  [SecurityUtils doAES:[plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] context: kCCEncrypt error:error];
    return [result base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}


+ (NSString *)decrypt:(NSString *)encryptedBase64String error:(NSError **)error {
    NSData *dataToDecrypt = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encryptedBase64String options:0];
    NSMutableData *result = [SecurityUtils doAES:dataToDecrypt context: kCCDecrypt error:error];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
}

+ (NSMutableData *)doAES:(NSData *)dataIn context:(CCOperation)kCCEncrypt_or_kCCDecrypt error:(NSError **)error {
        CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
        size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
        NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeBlowfish];
        NSData *key =[KEY dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *iv = [IV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        
        ccStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt_or_kCCDecrypt,
                           kCCAlgorithmAES,
                           kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                           key.bytes,
                           key.length,
                           (iv)?nil:iv.bytes,
                           dataIn.bytes,
                           dataIn.length,
                           dataOut.mutableBytes,
                           dataOut.length,
                           &cryptBytes);
        
        if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
            dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
        }
        else {
            if (error) {
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                             code:ccStatus
                                         userInfo:nil];
            }
            dataOut = nil;
        }
        
        return dataOut;
}


@end
```

**IOS TESTING**

```
NSError *error;
NSString *encrypted = [SecurityUtils encrypt:@"My Secret Text" error:&error];
NSLog(@"encrypted: %@",encrypted);
NSLog(@"decrypted: %@",[SecurityUtils decrypt:encrypted error:&error]);
```

Finally, the outputs of the test:

**ANDROID OUTPUT**

```
2019-05-16 21:35:01.215 4920-4920/br.com.my.app E/encrypted: EJ41am5W1k6fA7ygFjTSEw==
2019-05-16 21:35:01.215 4920-4920/br.com.my.app E/decrypted: My Secret Text
```

**IOS OUTPUT**

```
2019-05-16 21:38:02.947043-0300 MyApp[63392:1590665] encrypted: EJ41am5W1k6fA7ygFjTSEw==
2019-05-16 21:38:02.947270-0300 MyApp[63392:1590665] decrypted: My Secret Text
```

[My repo](https://github.com/juliancorrea/aes-crypto-android-and-ios) on GitHub with this example.

Comment: This approach to AES doesn't match the original Android code, so this isn't really an answer. You rcode also has significant security issues, and so should not be used as a replacement for the original code, either (the original code also has security problems, though they're a bit different). It's not safe to reuse the same key+IV combination in CBC. The fact that the Android and iOS encryptions match actually indicates a security flaw. In a correct encryption system, the output for the same password+message will be different every time. Also you key is shorter than you mean it to be.

Comment: Hi @RobNapier .My answer does not have the purpose to cover security issues. Just solved a technical compatibility problem which is the goal of the posted question.

Comment: @JulianCorrêa which class to import in android Base64.encodeBytes() in this function ?

Comment: Fair! @Maveňツ the Base64 class is from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/2.3/

However, the java 1.8 already have a Base64 class, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html


I've updated my repo with the Base64 class right now. Check it out!
Tks

Comment: @JulianCorrêa Done with that and now my android is working but characters length more than 15 can't be decrypted and throws bad padding exception. Any idea about that

Comment: Its a case more specific. I think that will be better we conversation by email. If we found the solution, you back here and post it. My email -> sof@juliancorrea.com.br

Comment: @JulianCorrêa thanks for the reply I will try to send sample code for both ios and android on your email